# Applying variable operands to operators

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an in the form:

```
data:[
   { operator: '*', operand1: 45, operand2: 80 },
   { operator: '*', operand1: 14, operand2: 47 },
   { operator: '+', operand1: 80, operand2: 6  }
];
```

I need to parse through the JSON data and return an array of answers. I am confused as to how to "apply" the variable operator to the operands. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a map of operators to to functions that, when invoked, carry out the operator, eg:

```js
const operatorFns = {
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '+': (a, b) => a + b
  // etc
};

const data = [
   { operator: '*', operand1: 45, operand2: 80 },
   { operator: '*', operand1: 14, operand2: 47 },
   { operator: '+', operand1: 80, operand2: 6  }
];

const results = data.map(item => operatorFns[item.operator](item.operand1, item.operand2));
console.log(results);
```